# Can anybody identify this uniform?

Tags: identification, uniform, photograph

This is an old family photo. Can anybody identify the uniforms in this picture?

My family was from Russia/Ukraine/Belarus.

Any other info would be cool -- about the medals?

[image: Three men in uniform; two seated in a light colored uniform, one standing in dark uniform.]

Comment: Supply a verbose description of the image allowing the blind or a search engine to recognise what is being depicted.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely they are Imperial Russian army uniforms. The giveaway is the double-headed eagle on the the buckle of the standing soldier. *[Wikipedia:Coat_of_arms_of_Russia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Russia)*

The white tunics are characteristic of soldiers who fought for Russia during the 1905 war with Japan. In 1907 uniforms were changed to a khaki type so the photograph is likely dated before that year. *[RBTH.com](https://www.rbth.com/arts/2015/03/03/the_last_hurrah_of_the_russian_imperial_uniform_41727)*

The standing soldier has a double breasted tunic with a single stripe on his shoulder. The single stripe indicates an enlisted soldier of the second rank. *[Wikipedia:Imperial_Russian_Army](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Russian_Army)*

@justCal has identified one of the medals as an 'excellence in shooting' medal. *[emedals.com](https://www.emedals.com/europe/russia/badges/a-russian-imperial-shooting-excellence-badge-grade-two)*

Comment: You may be correct - but direct visual comparison to documented examples is the standard generally expected here. If you can dig up images for the uniforms and other details described in your post, I expect you will garner up-votes.

Comment: Hi, Excel r 8, welcome to the History stack. You might note that answers are better received when they are accompanied by sources (and better yet links to sources) for the information. (beat me to it @PieterGeerkens)

Comment: By the way, if you wish to expand your answer, I had ID'd one of the medals as probably an 'excellence in [shooting' medal](https://www.emedals.com/europe/russia/badges/a-russian-imperial-shooting-excellence-badge-grade-two)

Answer (score 1):

The 2 soldiers sitting are wearing the khaki Gymnastiorka which was officially issued from 1908 (before this date they were white but soldiers disregarding regulations changed the colour to Khaki due to environment such as during the Russo Japanese war) and the man standing is wearing the 1907 double breasted tunic thus dating after 1907.

[image]
(source: [bergenschild.ru](http://bergenschild.ru/Reconstruction/depot/1912-18/nevskii01/nevskii_05.jpg))